# read certain cell from csv file

Tags: c++, csv

I am new to c++.
I want to read certain cells from my csv file.
I found a lot example but I still do not have any idea..

```
#ifndef PIZZACRUST_H
#define PIZZACRUST_H
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class PizzaCrust{

    private:

        int crustOpt;
        ifstream crustInput;
        char crust[200];

    public:

        PizzaCrust();
        void setCrustOption(int crustOpt);

}
;

#endif
```

---

this is the cpp

```
#include "pizzacrust.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

    PizzaCrust::PizzaCrust()
    {

        crustInput.open("pizzacrust.csv");

            while(crustInput)
            {
                crustInput.getline(crust, 200);
                cout << crust << endl;
            }

        crustInput.close();

    }

    void PizzaCrust::setCrustOption(int crustoption)
    {

        cout << "Please select the style of crust: ";
        cin >> crustoption;

            if ( crustoption > 0 && crustoption < 5 )
            {

                cout<<"You have selected " << crustoption << endl;

            }

            else
            {

                cout<<"Your selection is unavailable, please re-select from 1-4."<<endl;
                cin >> crustoption;

                cout<<"You have selected " << crustoption << endl;

            }

    }
```

and this is the csv file

[image]

how can i read only this cell, example it is a1 and a2??

"1. Pan Pizza

Crisp on the outside, fluffy on the inside. Handmade with our signature dough recipe and baked to golden perfection."

Comment: Please show some *actual* contents of the input file, not anything edited. I.e. copy-paste from the actual file.

Comment: Doesn't look much like a `.csv` format to me. what's the separator used for the cells?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), that's a screenshot of a program like Excel or similar. And from that screenshot (why post screenshot of a *text file*?) it seems that the "separator" is not a comma or semicolon (which are common) but a newline.

So to read the first record in the file, you need to read two lines. To read the fourth record you need to read (and possibly discard) 3*3 lines before you can read the two lines (three with the end-of-record empty line) of data.

If you want to read all records, you need to read three lines in a loop, perhaps something like

```
std::string crust;
std::string description;
while (std::getline(crustInput, crust) &&
       std::getline(crustInput, description))
{
    // Use the data read from the file somehow

    std::string empty;   // The empty line between the records
    std::getline(crustInput, empty);  // Read and discard the empty line
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new in c++ .. how can I read two lines only instead of all? as this system is ask the user to choose a pizza crust, if the user enter 1, I want to show "You have selected 1. Pan Pizza

Comment: @Carrine Each "record" in the file is three lines: the first with the number crust-type; The second with the description; And the third being an empty line separating the records. So if the user enters a value X then you need to skip (X - 1) * 3 lines in the file, in a loop very similar to the one I show in my answer. Then read two lines (and only two lines) for the data.